Get page source as bytes in python selenium
With the requests library, you can do this to get the site content as bytes:
requests.get("https://httpbin.org/get").content

There is a specific reason why I am using selenium instead of the requests library to basically do a GET request.
This 4 year old answer uses requests instead of selenium, this 3 year old forum post doesn't have any answers, and this 13 year old question doesn't include getting the page source as bytes.
Is there a way to get the page source as bytes instead of a string?

While not nearly as active as StackOverflow, there is a StackExchange site dedicated to Software Quality Assurance that accepts all selenium related questions. Full disclosure, I am a moderator there, but even if I wasn't I would have suggested it.
